# Cant use array-contains-any in firebase. It is not acceptable value. Why?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using firebase backend, firestore db. I have collection contacts. There are allot of documents, and i want to get all docs, where `phone` field, its an array, has any of given values.

So here is the code:

```
    const { db } = require('../../../admin')
const cleanPhoneNumber = require('../../../utilities/cleanPhoneNumber')

const getContactBy = async ({ phone }) => {
  const collectionRef = db.collection('contacts')

  if (phone) {
    const preparedPhones = phone.map((val) => `+${cleanPhoneNumber(val)}`)
    collectionRef.where('phones', 'array-contains-any', preparedPhones)
  }

  const contactId = await collectionRef.get().then((docRef) => docRef.id)
  return contactId
}

module.exports = getContactBy
```

So i'm passing phone array with string values into my function:

```
[ '79213333332' ]
```

But i'm getting error from firebase, that array-contains-any is not acceptable. I cant figureout why.

There is official [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any), that i CAN use it!
What's wrong with me, or firebase docs?

[image]

Comment: Please keep in mind these queries are limited to 30 disjunctions based on the query's disjunctive normal form due to official documentary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using an old version of the JavaScript client library. array-contains-any wasn't added until [version 7.3.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_730_-_november_7_2019).  The latest version is 7.14.0, so be sure to upgrade to the latest.

Comment: i had 5.9.0 v. Thx!